# Finding the derivative of a point given only a graph

Tags: calculus

So we are given a graph with 3 curves that intersects the positive x-axis 4 times.

[image: Graph]
Then asked to estimate the values of $f '(1)$, $f '(2)$ and so on until $f ' (5)$.
I'm assuming we are supposed to find the slope of the tangent line at $x=1$, $x=2$ and so on while estimating the y value for an approximate point. But I have no idea how to even begin since we don't have the original function to find the derivative of...

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

1. Note you have local maximum at $x=1$ and $x=4$, and alocal min around $2.5$. What is $f'$ at those points?
2. Is $f$ increasing or decreasing on $(1,2.5)$? What is the sign of $f'$ there?
3. Compare to a line parring roughly through the same points $(1,2)$ and $(2.5, -3)$ - what is the slope of the line, is $f$ increasing or decreasing faster?

Comment: So, at the local max and min points f ' would be 0 right, we didn't cover Fermat's theorem for very long. And at (1, 2.5) f is increasing so the sign of f ' would be positive, but the slope of (1,2) and (2.5, -3) is -3.3 because its decreasing faster.

Comment: @WMae not sure about relevance of Fermat's theorem, but yes, $f' = 0$ at local minima and maxima.

Comment: because its Fermat's theorem that says if f has a local extremum at an interior point, c, and f ' (c) exists, then f ' (c)=0. But we didn't go over practical applications of that

Comment: @WMae somehow that result was never presented to me as Fermat's theorem. happy to learn this from you :-)